# Read from file and return array of string in C

Tags: c

I know there are plenty of tutorials on the internet and most of them here on StackOverflow for this subject but I am having some issue implementing it. And I have no other solution but asking you for help.

I am trying to implement a function that reads from a file multiple lines stores them into an array and then passes back the info so I can build a linked list from it.

My function is:

```
void read_file(char *out_file, char* strings[])
{
    int i = 0;

    do{
        pthread_mutex_lock(&out_file_mutex);
        char content[1024];
        int counter = 0;
        FILE* fp = fopen(out_file, "r");
        if (fp)
        {           
           //  for each line read and add to array 
            while (fscanf(fp, "%s", content) == 1) 
            {
               strings[counter] = content;
               counter++;               
            }
            fclose(fp);
            i = 21;
        }
        else
        {
            sleep(1);
        }       

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&out_file_mutex);

   }while( i < 20 );
}
```

And I call it like this.

```
    if( (access( "test.csv", 0 )) != -1 )
    {       
        char *strings[1024];
        read_file("test.csv", strings); 

        int num = sizeof(strings) / sizeof(strings[0]);

        for(int i = 0; i< num - 1; i++)
        {
            if(strings[i] == NULL)
                break;

            listdata* ld = (listdata*)malloc(sizeof(listdata));
            strcpy(ld->content, strings[i]);                   
            ld->next = NULL;
            add_data_at_end(ld);
        }
    }
```

My issue is that the function is passing back an array that has only the last line.

Example:

In the file, I have the following lines.

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
```

Back in the main in the for loop I get:

```
Line4
Line4
Line4
Line4
```

So basically the last line * how many lines are in the file.

Any help is appreciated as I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `content` is a local variable inside the `do ... while` loop. Each time the loop iterates, the variable goes out of scope and its life-time ends, making pointers to it invalid. You need to allocate memory for the string dynamically, and later free them. And don't forget that `char` strings in C are *null-terminated*, and that the null-terminator also needs space.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you for the explanation, now I understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`content` is a local variable. Therefore, every time you assign it (point to it), you actually point to the same place in memory.
this is the reason you get the same result 4 times.
since it is located on the stack, it is actually surprising you get a reasonable result. The stack memory is out of scope when the function terminates and might be overwritten.

you need to allocate heap memory by using `strdup`.

```
strings[counter] = strdup(content);
```

do not forget to check that memory allocation succeed. Also you must release the memory calling `free()`

Comment: It should be noted that `strdup` is not a standard C function. It's a POSIX standard function, and exists also in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%s", content) == 1) 
        {
           strings[counter] = content;
```

this is assigning the SAME pointer to each entry in `strings[]`.

Suggest:

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%s", content) == 1) 
        {
           strings[counter] = strdup( content );
```

And, to avoid a memory leak, before exiting your program, pass each of those pointers in `strings[]` to `free()`

and to make calling `free()` a simple loop, suggest:

```
char *strings[1024] = {NULL};
```